# Visual Studio 2008 Read values from XSD file

Tags: xsd

First post. I am trying to read the values of any XSD in Visual Basic. I want the application to read back values like complextypes, elements etc. I have been looking at MSXML2 but most examples include validation against a XML file. I only want to read XSD and get information. Will xml reader be able to read a XSD file? Any help be great.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what you're trying to do with this information, therefore the prerequisites you need to have in place before doing it.

For all but really trivial tasks, I recommend the use of classes in [System.Xml.Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.aspx) namespace, particularly start with [XmlSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.aspx) and [XmlSchemaSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.aspx). This would allow you to manipulate XSDs any way you want; it would also allow you to validate the schemas before using them, if it would prove to be a requirement.

For completeness, and for what I would call very simple tasks, you may also think that XSD is just XML, so then any XML processor should allow you to load an XSD and interogate it as needed.

All of the above, since you've mentioned VS2008, would be on Visual Basic.NET. If you're still on Visual Basic and need to rely on MSXML, then I would refer you to this article on using [Visual Basic and SOM](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312554).